# Creating a redirect in htaccess for incoming requests

Tags: .htaccess

how can i redirect all requests coming on

```
foo.bar.com/some-thing
```

to be redirected to

```
foo.bar.com/some-thing-else
```

also can you please hook me up to some good learning resources for learning htaccess, i am very new to this development stuff.

Regards.

**Edit**
following is the code i have been trying with (without success)

```
RewriteRule ^some-thing?$  index.php/some-thing-else [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Duplicate question there are lot of questions on this

Comment: @Sandeep Manne exactly but i was unable to parse those questions and use them in my scenario

Comment: could you add some code you have tried with, so we can see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: i have figured it out cant answer my questions coz of my less reputation ... tnx everybody  for the consideration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this :
in the .htaccess put this :

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)-thing?$  index.php?route=$1-thing-else [QSA,L]
```

in the index php put this for testing :

```
<?php echo var_dump( $_GET ); ?>
```

browse to your site ie `http://localhost/some-thing` or `http://localhost/dirty-thing`.

hope you can modify this to your exact needs.

Answer (score 1):

It is `mod_rewrite` Apache module what you should be working with to do such redirects. It's not simple to learn, still very powerful tool. There are multiple tutorials learning it. Try http://www.easymodrewrite.com/ for beginning.